# how to hide a button in particular condition?

Tags: reactjs

How hide the button in a particular condition

```
{ !groupAccountPatientView && location.pathname.includes('group-accounts') &&
                     <button title="Main Patient" onClick={() =>browserHistory.push(`/patients/${patientInfo.PatientID}/`)} className="dashboard-patients-header_user">
                     <UserSolidIcon/>
                     </button>

                     ||
                     <div className="patients-header_extras">
                    <div className="patients-header_extras_switch">  
                      {!groupAccountPatientView && <button title="Patient Group" onClick={() =>browserHistory.push(totalGroupedPatientCount >1 ? `/patients/${patientInfo.PatientID}/group-accounts`: '#')} className="patients-header_extras_group patients-header_extras_switch_button">
                      <PatientsGroupIcon />
                      <span>({totalGroupedPatientCount>1?totalGroupedPatientCount:0})</span>
                      </button>}
                      </div>
```

this is my condition

```
totalGroupedPatientCount !==0
```

When count equal to show doesn't have to show the button otherwise show it. How it possible??

Comment: Weather count has a numerical value or a character. Please update the qiestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just insert `(totalGroupedPatientCount !==0) &&` or `!!totalGroupedPatientCount &&` before `<button` like you did with`!groupAccountPatientView &&`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it, using a very contrived example.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showButton: false
  };
  render() {
    const { showButton } = this.state;
    let button;

    if (showButton) {
      button = <button>Some Button</button>;
    } else {
      button = null;
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {button}
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You could also do it inline, which is what I prefer

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showButton: true
  };
  render() {
    const { showButton } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {showButton && <button> Hello </button>}
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `{showButton && <button> Hello </button>}` is shorter ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can  define a state `totalGroupedPatientCount`

And then you add this to show your component when the condition is true

```
{ this.state.showMyComponent && <MyComponent /> }
```